# can't copy/paste from/to virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I've set up all the necessary things I need to copy/paste from/to my virtual box.

[image]

[image]

Yet I still can't do it. What am I missing?

I'm on Windows 10;  Virtual Box 6.1.34; Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Insert guest additions CD image, run the software on it. i.e. install the Visual basic driver

Comment: done, I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kbez-XdXqrw but it still didn't work

Comment: Reboot that pesky Windows thing? ;.)

Comment: Mount the `Guest Additions CD` under the Devices ->  Insert Guest Additions CD Image... menu. Then run the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` from the mounted CD as sudo in your VM.  Once done, reboot your VM.

Comment: @Terrance thanks! that did it